# How to keep submit button on screen (Responsiveness)

Tags: css, asp.net-core, responsive-design, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I'm using Mud Blazor, Blazor Server, C#, etc. to create a simple form.  If the screen is small (mobile etc), I'd like for a vertical scroll bar to show and for the submit button to stay on the screen all the time just under the form content.  Is there a good way to do this with the Mud Blazor framework?  Or would this need to be done just with CSS?  Struggled with this quite a bit today.